# What is the best way to implement a Fraction type in C++?

Tags: c++, stl, fractions

I would like to handle rational numbers (possibly negative) in a C++ program, in a clean and effective way because they will be *heavily* used. And I mean, heavily.

I can code a textbook-style `Fraction` class that has 2 integer attributes, overloads all common operators, uses a gcd algorithm trick in the constructor, and all this stuff. The usual suspects of any decent C++ course.

However my instinct is that someone, possibly even the STL programmers, has already done this in a much, much better way than I would. Any best practice on this subject ?

Comment: Something like [`std::ratio`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio)?

Comment: I thought about this but my impression is that it’s not really meant to handle actual values, more like constant multiplicative factors at compile-time. Also, I read on a website that the ratio is not represented by an object of this type, and that `ratio` cannot contain any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would Boost Rational Numbers fit your needs ?
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/rational/rational.html